# Using underscore to get all keys and list of unique values for each

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

Starting with an array of objects, I need get a list of all keys and all the unique values for each. The problem is that I don't know the keys beforehand. There are plenty of solutions if you know the key, but in this case each object can have any number of keys and each key has an array of values. The code below works, but it's quite complicated and there must be a simpler solution.

[Made a working JSBIN here](https://jsbin.com/ladexomopo/7/edit?js,console)

Input:

```
[
    {
        key_1: [ attribute_value_1, attribute_value_2, ... ],
        key_2: [ attribute_value_3, attribute_value_4, ... ],
    },
    ...
]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        label: key_1,
        options: [ attribute_value_1, attribute_value_2, ... ]
    },
    {
        label: key_2,
        options: [ attribute_value_3, attribute_value_4, ... ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Suggested Solution:

```
    _.chain(input)
        .map(function (attr) {
            return _.keys(attr).map(function (key) {
                return {
                    key: key,
                    value: attr[key]
                };
            });
        })
        .flatten()
        .groupBy('key')
        .map(function (grouped_values, key) {
            // value = array of { key, value }
            return {
                label: key,
                options: _.chain(grouped_values)
                    .pluck('value')
                    .flatten()
                    .uniq()
                    .value()
            };
        })
        .value();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lodash - Apply [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#mergeWith) to the input array, and use the customizer function to combine the arrays and get the unique values. Afterwards [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#map) the result to the required format:

```js
var input = [
  {
    key_1: [ "attribute_value_1", "attribute_value_2" ],
    key_2: [ "attribute_value_3", "attribute_value_4" ]
  },
  {
    key_1: [ "attribute_value_1", "attribute_value_5" ],
    key_2: [ "attribute_value_2", "attribute_value_3" ],
    key_5: [ "attribute_value_2", "attribute_value_3" ]
  }
];


var params = [{}].concat(input).concat(function (objValue, srcValue) { // create the params to apply to mergeWith
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return _.union(objValue, srcValue); // merge the arrays, and get the unique values
  }
});

var result = _.map(_.mergeWith.apply(_, params), function(value, key) { // merge all objects in the array, and map the results to required format
  return {
    label: key,
    options: value
    };
  });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And you can clean up the ugly `params` array if you use ES6:

```js
const input = [
  {
    key_1: [ "attribute_value_1", "attribute_value_2" ],
    key_2: [ "attribute_value_3", "attribute_value_4" ]
  },
  {
    key_1: [ "attribute_value_1", "attribute_value_5" ],
    key_2: [ "attribute_value_2", "attribute_value_3" ],
    key_5: [ "attribute_value_2", "attribute_value_3" ]
  }
];

const customizer = (objValue, srcValue) => {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return _.union(objValue, srcValue); // merge the arrays, and get the unique values
  }
};

const result = _.map(_.mergeWith({}, ...input, customizer), (value, key) => ({ // merge all objects in the array, and map the results to required format
  label: key,
  options: value
}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could write this in Underscore if you prefer, but there's no pressing need to do so.

```js
const input = [
  {key_1: [1, 2], key_2: [3, 4]},
  {key_3: [5, 6], key_2: [7, 42]}
 ];

var result = [].concat(...input.map(obj => 
  Object.keys(obj).map(key =>
    ({label: key, options: obj[key]})
  )
));

console.log(result);
```

I'm not quite sure how you want to uniqify the result. Do you mean that you want to run unique within each array such as `[ attribute_value_1, attribute_value_2, ... ]`?

Comment: That's really nice, but doesn't quite do what I wanted. If you run the code there will be two separate entries for "key_2", so there would have to be another step that groups the array by label.
What does the [].concat(... x ) achieve? I would just run input.map()